# Openshift: permission denied while installing New Relic Jar file

Tags: openshift, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am trying to install new-relic jar to my Openshift application (wildfly cartridge), but it fails with `permission denied`. Here is the log

```
\> java -jar newrelic.jar install
Jan 29, 2015 15:01:14 -0500 [64858 1] com.newrelic INFO: Agent is using Logback
***** ( ( o))  New Relic Java Agent Installer
***** Installing version 3.13.0 ...
Problem writing file to disk
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/openshift/544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf.20150129_150114 (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:95)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.write(EditableFile.java:273)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.backup(EditableFile.java:251)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.SelfInstaller.backup(SelfInstaller.java:125)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEdit(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:51)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEditStartScript(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:35)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.installCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:138)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.parseCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:81)
    at com.newrelic.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:261)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent.main(BootstrapAgent.java:84)
Problem writing file to disk
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/openshift/544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:95)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.write(EditableFile.java:273)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.write(EditableFile.java:263)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.append(EditableFile.java:240)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEdit(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:55)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEditStartScript(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:35)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.installCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:138)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.parseCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:81)
    at com.newrelic.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:261)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent.main(BootstrapAgent.java:84)
Added agent switch to start script /var/lib/openshift/544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf
Problem writing file to disk
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/openshift/544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf.20150129_150114 (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:95)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.write(EditableFile.java:273)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.backup(EditableFile.java:251)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.SelfInstaller.backup(SelfInstaller.java:125)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEdit(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:51)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEditStartScript(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:37)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.installCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:138)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.parseCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:81)
    at com.newrelic.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:261)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent.main(BootstrapAgent.java:84)
Problem writing file to disk
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/openshift/544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:95)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:63)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.write(EditableFile.java:273)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.write(EditableFile.java:263)
    at com.newrelic.agent.util.EditableFile.append(EditableFile.java:240)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEdit(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:55)
    at com.newrelic.agent.install.JBoss7SelfInstaller.backupAndEditStartScript(JBoss7SelfInstaller.java:37)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.installCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:138)
    at com.newrelic.agent.AgentCommandLineParser.parseCommand(AgentCommandLineParser.java:81)
    at com.newrelic.agent.Agent.main(Agent.java:261)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.newrelic.bootstrap.BootstrapAgent.main(BootstrapAgent.java:84)
Added agent switch to start script /var/lib/openshift/544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf
No need to create New Relic configuration file because:
 .:. A config file already exists: /var/lib/openshift/544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253/wildfly/newrelic/newrelic.yml
***** Install successful
***** Next steps:
You're almost done! To see performance data for your app:
 .:. Restart your app server
 .:. Exercise your app
 .:. Log into http://rpm.newrelic.com
Within two minutes, your app should show up, ready to monitor and troubleshoot.
If app data doesn't appear, check newrelic/logs/newrelic_agent.log for errors.
```

How can I install it? Where can I get permission?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NewRelic is attempting to create a backup of the WildFly configuration file which it finds at `~/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf`. Unfortunately it fails due because the `~/wildfly/bin` is *locked* by the WildFly cartridge as you can see by its permissions and entry in the cartridge's `managed_files.yml`:

```
\> ls -ld wildfly/bin/
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root 544c2c3be0b8cdf8da000253 4096 Dec 23 20:01 wildfly/bin/

\> cat wildfly/metadata/managed_files.yml
---
[...]
locked_files:
- bin/
- bin/*
[...]
```

I see three options, in order of complexity.

1. See if `newrelic.jar` accepts an flag to not perform a backup of the config file.
2. Since it looks like `newrelic.jar` is trying to automatically modify `standalone.conf` for you, try running this step on a local environment with WildFly where you do have permissions. Then check in the new `standalone.conf` to OpenShift git.
3. Fork the [WildFly cart repo](https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-wildfly-cartridge) and remove the `bin/` and `bin/*` entries from the `locked_files` key in `managed_files.yml`. But make sure to create these manually within the cart's `bin/setup` script, as locking would normally do that for you. See [Locking cartridges](https://docs.openshift.com/online/cartridge_specification_guide/locking_cartridges.html) for more info.